# How to correct Y values for GLM

Tags: rstudio, regression

Generalized Linear Modelling on R data set Trucks

When I tried to key in the formula, an error pops out saying that my y values should be between 0 and 1. Why does this occur?

This is for R studio. Data set is from R package - Trucks

This is the code I used

```
print (Data)
lrfit<-glm(Freq ~ +period +collision + parked +light , family = 
binomial (link = logit)glm
```

> `Error in eval (family$initialize) : y values must be 0<= y <= 1`

Comment: That is because you're trying to perform a logistic regression, where the response is usually expected to be 0 or 1, or in some specific cases can also be a probability between 0 and 1. What type of relationship are you trying to model? If its just a linear one then you dont need to use `glm` and can just use `lm` instead